# Tile out of range error when using wmts on Geoserver with Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, gis, layer, geoserver, wms

I'd like to render a layer from `geoserver` with using `WMTS`.
I'm using `mapbox-gl` to render a map and layers.

The website I'm referring to is `https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/mbstyle/source.html`.
This shows how to create a layer on geoserver and render it on a mapbox map.

However, I'm getting an error `TileOutOfRange` when I request tiles.

For example, when I request tiles with this url,
`http://<my_server>:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=myspace:japan&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:8&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL=221&TILEROW=102`.

I get this error message.
`Column 221 is out of range, min: 440 max:462`.

Here below is my code to fetch a layer that I created on geoserver.

```
map.on("load", () => {
        map.addSource("test", {
            type: "vector",
            tiles: ["http://<my_server>:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=GetTile&SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.0.0&LAYER=myspace:japan&STYLE=&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4326:{z}&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4326&FORMAT=application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile&TILECOL={x}&TILEROW={y}"],
            generateId: true,
            minZoom: 0,
            maxZoom: 14,
        });
    
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "test",
            "type": "fill",
            "source": "test",
            "source-layer": "japan",
            "layout": { "visibility": "visible" },
            "paint": {}
            
        });
    });
```

It would be much appreciated if anyone gave me a way to solve this.
Thank you.

- I made sure that I checked this box `application/vnd.mapbox-vector-tile` in the tile caching settings.
- I left out 900913 from the default gridset settings, since my data is EPSG:4326.
- When creating a layer, I made sure that I clicked `Compute from data` and `Compute from native bounds` to set bounding boxes.

Comment: You are asking for a tile that doesn't exist, pan to an area that is in the data

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  
According to the website that I referred to, Mapbox does that if I use {z}, {x}, {y} as parameters.   
Thus, I don't have to set that manually.

Comment: In my case, I am using the default 900913 gridset. My data is in another projection, but GeoServer should be reprojecting on the fly.